# HTML5 web Audio API CPU priority or prebuffer

Tags: html, web-audio-api

Is there a way to make priority for audio processing or a prebuffer using html5 audio API to avoid unsync, small breaks, when doing other non audio related processing? I rather have a continuous 500 ms latency than unsync. For example when I'm using lots of jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut simultaneously as having a cowbell at 128 bpm there can be small breaks/unsync on my iPhone. (Also on the iPhone when scrolling, zooming there is issues - but those I can solve by disabling that.)

Comment: I tried to capture audio from mic with native API's and came to the conclusion that one must use workers for any non-UI calculation when it's possible. Without dedicated worker I have had really distorted and chunked audio stream.

Comment: Thanks. Please clarify "worker" a little bit. I guess it's a free running process.. I'm a noob sometimes;)

Comment: Some kind of multi-threading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker